# Is there a secure way to allow JavaScript in user-generated content with subdomains?

Tags: security, cookies, subdomain, xss

Consider a blog site, where blogs have subdomains per user, say, `foo.blog.com` or `bar.blog.com` and are allowed to have JavaScript in layouts and posts.

Users log in to `www.blog.com` for editing, so cookie sandboxing would be a requirement.

What are the potential security risks of doing so, and what is a modern way to resolve the problems, only using the `blog.com` domain?